# xrmquery.update -> update crm id binding with null

Tags: typescript, dynamics-crm, crm, xrmquery

I need to use XrmQuery to update an id-binding field with "null".

Here is my code:

```
XrmQuery.update(x => x.contacts,
                recordId,
                {
                    address2_line1: null,
                    address2_postalcode: null,
                    address2_city: null,
                    cgk_origindate: null,
                    cgk_countrypostaladdressid_bind$cgk_countries: null,
                    cgk_originaddress: null
                }).execute(id => {
                });
```

The update does not work with `cgk_countrypostaladdressid_bind$cgk_countries: null`.

When I delete this line the update works fine. Is there a typical way to make an id-binding field "null" with XrmQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set lookup fields to null by sending an update-request to the Web API. Instead, you need to send a [disassociate request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607875.aspx#Anchor_2). Unfortunately we do not yet currently support associate/disassociate requests in [XrmQuery](https://github.com/delegateas/XrmDefinitelyTyped/wiki/XrmQuery-Web-API).

Until we have built support for this directly into XrmQuery ([issue 31](https://github.com/delegateas/XrmDefinitelyTyped/issues/31)), you can manually craft the request as follows: 
As you can see on the MSDN-page, you need to send an `HTTP DELETE` in a specific format. For lookups (which are called single-valued navigation properties) you can set their value to null as follows:

```
XrmQuery.sendRequest("DELETE",
  "contacts(" + recordId + ")/cgk_countrypostaladdressid/$ref",
  null,
  () => { alert("success"); },
  () => { alert("error"); }
);
```

Comment: Support for associate and disassociate has been added in version 3.0.2 of XrmDefinitelyTyped